# Converting a String to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm just going to get right into it.  I get an error in LogCat that says my JSON String can not be converted into a JSONOject and I really don't know how to work my around this error so I was just hoping somebody with better knowledge than me can give me advice on how I can attend to this issue

Logcat:

```
08-02 00:12:28.485: E/JSON Parser(778): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

JSONParser class

```
 public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is;
    JSONObject jObj;
    String json = "";
    public EditText et;

    public JSONParser () {
    }

    public JSONObject readJSONFeed(String URL) {

        try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        //request.setURI(website);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;

        }finally{}

    }{
    }}
```

This is the method that is causing this error to appear:

```
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
       Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

I've printed my JSON String:

```
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <html><head><title>Yahoo! - 404 Not Found</title><style>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): /* nn4 hide */ 
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): /*/*/
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): body {font:small/1.2em arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;font:x-small;text-align:center;}table {font-size:inherit;font:x-small;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): html>body {font:83%/1.2em arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;}input {font-size:100%;vertical-align:middle;}p, form {margin:0;padding:0;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): p {padding-bottom:6px;margin-bottom:10px;}#doc {width:48.5em;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid #fff;text-align:center;}#ygma {text-align:right;margin-bottom:53px}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): #ygma img {float:left;}#ygma div {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding-bottom:8px;margin-left:152px;}#bd {clear:both;text-align:left;width:75%;margin:0 auto 20px;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): h1 {font-size:135%;text-align:center;margin:0 0 15px;}legend {display:none;}fieldset {border:0 solid #fff;padding:.8em 0 .8em 4.5em;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): form {position:relative;background:#eee;margin-bottom:15px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-width:1px 0;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): #s1p {width:15em;margin-right:.1em;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): form span {position:absolute;left:70%;top:.8em;}form a {font:78%/1.2em arial;display:block;padding-left:.8em;white-space:nowrap;background: url(http://l.yimg.com/a/i/s/bullet.gif) no-repeat left center;} 
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): form .sep {display:none;}.more {text-align:center;}#ft {padding-top:10px;border-top:1px solid #999;}#ft p {text-align:center;font:78% arial;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): /* end nn4 hide */
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </style></head>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <body><div id="doc">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <div id="ygma"><a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://www.yahoo.com"><img
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): src=http://l.yimg.com/a/i/yahoo.gif
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): width=147 height=31 border=0 alt="Yahoo!"></a><div><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795):  - <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://help.yahoo.com">Help</a></div></div>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <div id="bd"><h1>Sorry, the page you requested was not found.</h1>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <p>Please check the URL for proper spelling and capitalization. If
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): you're having trouble locating a destination on Yahoo!, try visiting the
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <strong><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo! home
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): page</a></strong> or look through a list of <strong><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://docs.yahoo.com/docs/family/more/">Yahoo!'s
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): online services</a></strong>. Also, you may find what you're looking for
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): if you try searching below.</p>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <form name="s1" action="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*-http://search.yahoo.com/search"><fieldset>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <legend><label for="s1p">Search the Web</label></legend>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <input type="text" size=30 name="p" id="s1p" title="enter search terms here">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <input type="submit" value="Search">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <span><a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://search.yahoo.com/search/options?p=">advanced search</a> <span class=sep>|</span> <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://buzz.yahoo.com">most popular</a></span>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </fieldset></form>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <p class="more">Please try <strong><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://help.yahoo.com">Yahoo!
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): Help Central</a></strong> if you need more assistance.</p>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </div><div id="ft"><p>Copyright &copy; 2013 Yahoo! Inc.
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): All rights reserved. <a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://privacy.yahoo.com">Privacy
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): Policy</a> - <a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://docs.yahoo.com/info/terms/">Terms
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): of Service</a></p></div>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </div></body></html>
```

Comment: print your `json` string. It may not be a valid JOSN formatted string.

Comment: `<!doctype...` is not a valid JSON string. It looks like your trying to get the JSON parser to parse HTML. Please include your JSON string.

Comment: errrrrrrrrgh why people keep doing it by hand when `gSon` by Google is available... https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: try `Log.d("JSON String",json);` to see what the string actually contains and paste it here so that we can help.

Comment: @Md.AbdulMunim I have printed my JSON String

Comment: Check the answer from @MattDavis, it's exactly what you should take care of.

Answer (score 0):

You String has to be JSON encoded.  [See the android documentation for the constructor that you're attempting to use.](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)  This means that your string should look like this:

```
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }
```

Possibly with escaped quotes.

Based on your error message, it appears as though you're attempting to create the JSONObject from HTML or some other markup language.  You may want to verify that the URL you're making the call to actually returns valid JSON, and that you're adding all of the correct parameters and headers to prevent getting an error page as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try dis hope it will work for u

```
 public class TestObjectToJson {
      public int k1 = 1;
      public String k2 = "Test";

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          TestObjectToJson obj = new TestObjectToJson();
          Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);

          System.out.println(json);
      }

    }
```

For reference u can see this

```
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
```