# Android help need with json

Tags: android, json

I'm in need of a little help with encoding my JSON string to receive certain data from a web service. I already tried to format my JSON string the standard way which you will see below in my JSONParsser class but I was told that my JSON string was invalid which you can see here in my older question. [Converting a String to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021263/converting-a-string-to-jsonobject) I'm not asking anybody to do my code for me I'm just asking can you look at my code and let me know if there is any errors with my URL parameters and which I should encode my JSON string to receive the data from this web service.  Here is link to the URL parameters http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html and to see the data I'm trying to parse just look at the Json data not the class of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028570/yahoo-answers-json-parse

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button getanswer;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        Button getanswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        getanswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String searchTerm = et.getText().toString().trim();         
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListView.class);
            in.putExtra("TAG_SEARCH", searchTerm);
            startActivity(in);
        }


        });
    }}
```

ListView Activity:

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {    


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> questionList;    

     final String TAG_RESULTS = "results";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT = "Subject";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS = "NumAnswers";
     final String TAG_QUESTION = "Question";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT = "Content";
     final String TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER = "ChosenAnswer";
     final String TAG_ANSWERS = "Answers";
     final String TAG_ANSWER = "Answer";    
     final String TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT = "Content";      

            JSONArray results;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);      

         //questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    new LoadAllData().execute();
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == 100) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    class LoadAllData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog pDialog; 
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListView.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) pDialog.dismiss();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                Intent in = getIntent();
                String searchTerm = in.getStringExtra("TAG_SEARCH");
                String query = URLEncoder.encode(searchTerm, "utf-8");
                String URL = "http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswerService/V1/questionSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query="+ query +"search_in=question&sort=relevance&results=25&output=json&callback=ws_results";
                JSONParsser jParser = new JSONParsser();
                JSONObject jObj = jParser.readJSONFeed(URL);
                try {
                    results = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

                    for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                           JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);

                           JSONObject Question = r.getJSONObject(TAG_QUESTION);
                           String Subject = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT);
                           String NumAnswers = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS);
                           String ChosenAnswers= Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CHOSENANSWER);
                           String Content = Question.getString(TAG_QUESTION_CONTENT);

                           //JSONObject Answers = Question.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWERS);
                           //JSONObject Answer = Answers.getJSONObject(TAG_ANSWER);
                           //String Content1 = Answers.getString(TAG_ANSWERS_CONTENT);

                             questionList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, Subject);
                               map.put(TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS, NumAnswers);

                               questionList.add(map);

                           }



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return TAG_RESULTS ; 



        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_URL) {

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), questionList,
                        R.layout.listview,
                        new String[] { TAG_QUESTION_SUBJECT, TAG_QUESTION_NUMANSWERS }, new int[] {
                        R.id.Subject, R.id.NumAnswers });

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                android.widget.ListView lv = getListView();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }   

                });     

        }}

    }
```

JSONParsser:

```
public class JSONParsser {

    InputStream is;
    JSONObject jObj;
    String json = "";
    public EditText et;

    public JSONParsser () {
    }

    public JSONObject readJSONFeed(String URL) {

        try{
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
        //request.setURI(website);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        Log.d("JSON String",json);

        return jObj;

        }finally{}

    }{
    }}
```

This is my printed JSON string and if you understand it its just basically returning an error page from the web service:

```
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <html><head><title>Yahoo! - 404 Not Found</title><style>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): /* nn4 hide */ 
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): /*/*/
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): body {font:small/1.2em arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;font:x-small;text-align:center;}table {font-size:inherit;font:x-small;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): html>body {font:83%/1.2em arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif;}input {font-size:100%;vertical-align:middle;}p, form {margin:0;padding:0;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): p {padding-bottom:6px;margin-bottom:10px;}#doc {width:48.5em;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid #fff;text-align:center;}#ygma {text-align:right;margin-bottom:53px}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): #ygma img {float:left;}#ygma div {border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;padding-bottom:8px;margin-left:152px;}#bd {clear:both;text-align:left;width:75%;margin:0 auto 20px;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): h1 {font-size:135%;text-align:center;margin:0 0 15px;}legend {display:none;}fieldset {border:0 solid #fff;padding:.8em 0 .8em 4.5em;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): form {position:relative;background:#eee;margin-bottom:15px;border:1px solid #ccc;border-width:1px 0;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): #s1p {width:15em;margin-right:.1em;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): form span {position:absolute;left:70%;top:.8em;}form a {font:78%/1.2em arial;display:block;padding-left:.8em;white-space:nowrap;background: url(http://l.yimg.com/a/i/s/bullet.gif) no-repeat left center;} 
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): form .sep {display:none;}.more {text-align:center;}#ft {padding-top:10px;border-top:1px solid #999;}#ft p {text-align:center;font:78% arial;}
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): /* end nn4 hide */
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </style></head>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <body><div id="doc">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <div id="ygma"><a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://www.yahoo.com"><img
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): src=http://l.yimg.com/a/i/yahoo.gif
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): width=147 height=31 border=0 alt="Yahoo!"></a><div><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795):  - <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://help.yahoo.com">Help</a></div></div>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <div id="bd"><h1>Sorry, the page you requested was not found.</h1>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <p>Please check the URL for proper spelling and capitalization. If
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): you're having trouble locating a destination on Yahoo!, try visiting the
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <strong><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo! home
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): page</a></strong> or look through a list of <strong><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://docs.yahoo.com/docs/family/more/">Yahoo!'s
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): online services</a></strong>. Also, you may find what you're looking for
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): if you try searching below.</p>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <form name="s1" action="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*-http://search.yahoo.com/search"><fieldset>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <legend><label for="s1p">Search the Web</label></legend>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <input type="text" size=30 name="p" id="s1p" title="enter search terms here">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <input type="submit" value="Search">
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <span><a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://search.yahoo.com/search/options?p=">advanced search</a> <span class=sep>|</span> <a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://buzz.yahoo.com">most popular</a></span>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </fieldset></form>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): <p class="more">Please try <strong><a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://help.yahoo.com">Yahoo!
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): Help Central</a></strong> if you need more assistance.</p>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </div><div id="ft"><p>Copyright &copy; 2013 Yahoo! Inc.
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): All rights reserved. <a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://privacy.yahoo.com">Privacy
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): Policy</a> - <a
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/404/*http://docs.yahoo.com/info/terms/">Terms
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): of Service</a></p></div>
08-02 20:02:27.535: D/JSON String(795): </div></body></html>
```

Comment: as answered in the question you linked: the stuff you post is *not* JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Your url:

```
http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswerService/V1/questionSearch
```

The correct url:

```
http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch
```

Notice the difference `AnswerService` should be `AnswersService`. You also have an error here:

```
...&query="+ query +"search...
```

Should be

```
...&query="+ query +"&search...
```

Because all query parameters have to be delimited by an ampersand. [Here is an example of the url in action](http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=how%20to%20spell&search_in=question&sort=relevance&results=25&output=json&callback=ws_results). Note that you probably need to get your own app id because that id gave me an error. It looks like you're using a demo app id that is provided by Yahoo for examples.

Comment: thank you it is now returning data and also can you have a look at my new question stackoverflow.com/questions/18138808/… it is still about yahoo answers and since you are familiar I was hoping you could help me